# Converting Three and Four Digit Integers to Dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this column in my data frame:

```
date
1026
1115
125
314
```

I want to convert them to dates.  The months range from October to April (it covers the NBA season) so October, November and December will have a different year attached to them than January, February, March and April.

As a start I had tried converting them from `int` to `str` and then running this `for` loop to insert / with the plan to add the year on in another step:

```
for i in range(0,len(nba_lines.index)):
    nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'] = nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][:2] + '/' + nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][2:]
```

It works well for the four-digit numbers, 1026 to 10/26, but the / in the three-digit numbers ends up in the wrong place, 314 to 31/4.

Then I tried to do an `if` instead based on the length of the string:

```
    if len(nba_lines[i,'Date']) == 3:
        nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'] = nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][:1] + '/' + nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][1:]
    else:
        nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'] = nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][:2] + '/' + nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][2:]
```

but that returns `KeyError: (0, 'Date')`.  I tried changing from `loc` to `iloc` and I got the same error.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: if you have for example 125 how do you know if it is Desember 5th or January 25th? Same for 314 - March 14th or April 31st?

Comment: October, November and December (1205) are four-digit numbers in the column and January(125), February, March and April are three-digit numbers.

Comment: does it mean day is always 2 digits? In which case you can take month as d[:-2] and day as d[-2:] where d is respective number converted to str?

Comment: Yes, the day is always the last two digits.  The month can be one or two digits.

Comment: in this case your first snippet should work fine with negative indexes as I show in my comment

Comment: That worked out perfectly and it helped me figure out how to complete the second part, adding on the year.  Thank you.

Comment: In this case I will post my comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

Given the info that day is always 2 digits and month is either 1 or 2 digits - first snippet would work as expect with negative indexes

```
for i in range(0,len(nba_lines.index)):
    nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'] = nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][:-2] + '/' + nba_lines.loc[i,'Date'][-2:]
```